# PYTHON 3.10: List comprehension raising error for str.strip() and str.replace() unexpectedly

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to strip a set of quotes around string items in a list but I am seeing an error raised. It seems I distinctly remember doing this operation before but conveniently I could not find a previous code project where I did it in a quick cursory. Here is my code:

```
    result = cur.fetchall() # result = (1, 2, 3,) or result = ((1, 3), (4, 5),)

    result = [list(item) for item in result]

    final_result = [item.strip("'", "") for item in result]

except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)

finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()

return final_result
```

**The result of this code is:
'list' object has no attribute 'strip'**

I did also try .strip() but same type of error was raised. Am I missing something/forgetting a nuance of python 3.x?

Comment: Also adding that I tried to over-solve by using the .join() to send it back to string then in the same operation break back into list with character stripped, and lo and behold same type of error raised. I am fairly adept at Python so I'm a bit lost on this one.

Comment: lists don't have strip as an attribute, meaning you can't call `.strip()` on a list, and you define each item of `result` as a list. So maybe try `[[elem.strip("'") for elem in item] for item in result]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you start from `result = ((1, 3), (4, 5),)` as indicated in the comment, after:

```
result = [list(item) for item in result]
```

`result` will be a list of lists:

```
[[1, 3], [4, 5]]
```

When calculating `final_result` you iterate over that list of lists and apply `strip` on the item (which is a list), hence the error appears:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: Thank you Dan. Yes, I finally realized my error and switched to a nested list comprehension statement, which worked perfectly. For whatever reason I didn't recognize that I was nesting the list with that line.